# HAProxy - Reject connection if flodding server

Tags: tcp, block, haproxy

i want to reject the connection if the user spams the server with requests. My current config looks like this:

```
frontend http_front
   bind *:80
   log global
   stick-table type ip size 1m expire 1m store gpc0,http_req_rate(10s)
   # Increase gpc0 if requests in last 10s where greater than 10
   acl conn_rate_abuse  src_http_req_rate gt 10
   acl mark_as_abuser   src_inc_gpc0  gt 0

   tcp-request connection track-sc1 src
   # Reject if gpc0 greater than 1
   tcp-request connection reject if conn_rate_abuse mark_as_abuser

   default_backend http_back
```

The Socket- Output looks like this

`0x1e455c0: key=10.23.27.55 use=0 exp=51149 gpc0=0 http_req_rate(10000)=422`

What am i doing wrong?!

Edit://
With this code it works, but shouldnt it work with only the code above?

```
backend http_back
   balance roundrobin

   acl abuse src_http_req_rate(http_front) ge 10
   tcp-request content reject if abuse

   server test1 ip1:80 check
   server test2 ip2:80 check
```

HA-Proxy version 1.6.4 2016/03/13

Comment: You didn't mention what isn't working.  Are the connections still being allowed through?  Is there a reason you have declared 2 ACLs that do not seem to actually be referenced elsewhere in the logic?

Comment: Yeah, the connections are still going through...The acls set the variables conn_rate_abuse and mark_as_abuser and are not checked in this version, you are right (but it also didnt work). I'll update the post